# How to mimic Lua's table.pack() without `n` key

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm trying to rewrite my own `tablePack()` function that returns a table without `n`.

For example, calling `tablePack(1, 2, 3)` should return a table `{1, 2, 3}`.

How can I create the `tablePack()` function? Any advice would be appreciated.

---

**ADDED:**

Here's an example code:

```
local a = table.pack(1,2,3)
local b = {1,2,3}

print(a.n, b.n)
```

Result:

```
3   nil
```

How can I create my own `tablePack()` function so the result can be the following?

```
nil  nil
```

---

**ADDED2:**

Would this be the solution?

```
function tablePack(...)
  local r = table.pack(...)
  r.n = nil
  return r;
end
```

Maybe this is better?

```
function ofTable(...)
  return {...}
end
```

Comment: Why do you need a function to do something you can do with `{}` syntax? Pretty much *any time* you might want to call this `tablePack(...)` function, you could just as easily do `{...}` with the same stuff (so long as it is viable for an array). Also, if you don't provide the `n` element, then you won't be able to correctly handle embedded `nil` values.

Comment: @NicolBolas My host program doesn't allow users to use `{` and `}` key inputs. Wait, so all the tables contain `n` key as a default?

Comment: @NicolBolas Please see my edited post.

Comment: "*My host program doesn't allow users to use { and } key inputs.*" Who *exactly* cannot use those keys? Can `tablePack` use those keys? Also, Lua is not meant to be written without being able to use all of the available operators; if someone is being forbidden the use of `{}`, then you're forbidding them the use of Lua as a language. "*Wait, so all the tables contain n key as a default?*" No, but it's a useful feature if you ever intend to unpack it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ofTable` solution is best.

`table.pack` is useful when some of the arguments may be `nil`. The `n` field would let you either detect trailing `nil`s contained within the `...` or cope with the fact that `#`, `ipairs`, and most `table` functions won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my previous answer, please.

Your example of setting n to nil is perfectly acceptable and will work.

(Faulty code, please ignore:)

You could simply return the ellipses:

```
function tablePack(...)
    return ...;
end
```

There's also this:

```
function tablePack(...)
   local n = select("#", ...);
   local t = debug.getinfo(0);
   for k in pairs(t) do
      t[k] = nil;
   end
   for i = 1, n do
      local e = select(i, ...);
      table.insert(t, e);
   end
   return t;
end

local t = tablePack(1,2,3);

print("length: " .. #t);

for e in pairs(t) do
   print(e);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local unpack = unpack or table.unpack

function SafePack(...)
    local params = {...}
    params.n = select('#', ...)
    return params
end

function SafeUnpack(safe_pack_tb)
    return unpack(safe_pack_tb, 1, safe_pack_tb.n)
end

function ConcatSafePack(safe_pack_l, safe_pack_r)
   local concat = {}
   for i = 1,safe_pack_l.n do
      concat[i] = safe_pack_l[i]
   end
   for i = 1,safe_pack_r.n do
      concat[safe_pack_l.n + i] = safe_pack_r[i]
   end
   concat.n = safe_pack_l.n + safe_pack_r.n
   return concat
end
```

You can use `SafePack` and `SafeUnPack` to replace them